# PHPMailer & WordPress "Post by Email" - not creating post

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I'm creating a script for a client using their PHP 5.4.16 (updating is not in the scope of this project), and therefore PHPMailer 5.2.25. My script (below) works if I change the SetAddress to my personal Gmail account (I get the email with subject, body, and attachment (the latter being the reason for using PHPMailer)), but if I change the SetAddress to my WordPress "Post by Email" address, nothing seems to be delivered.

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with my script? Missing headers? Badly formatted email?
2. If my script is apparently OK, what other avenues of investigation might there be?

Thanks

```
<?php
echo "<p>" . date("h:i:sa");
?>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/../www/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php'); ?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../www/phpmailer/class.smtp.php'); ?>

<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages     only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "my@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";

$mail->From     = "my@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Me";
//$mail->AddAddress("caju317davu@post.wordpress.com");
$mail->AddAddress("my@gmail.com");
$mail->AddReplyTo("my@gmail.com","developer");
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../www/_assets/articles/223/610/7f10120230e612e03eea9aa54a48a68f.jpg', 'attachment.jpg');

$mail->Subject  = "My test email";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! This is my first successful post created through email.";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: "updating is not in the scope of this project" Is repairing a hacked server in the scope of the project? Because it will be, sooner or later, with an emphasis on the *sooner*.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am not sure if this will help at all but below is the code that I have for a working version of PHPMailer v5.2.9 that is running on a site using PHP version 5.4.16 so may help. The obvious differences I can see is the recipient's section don't have "set" or "Add" and also I can't seem to find the initiator ($mail->send();). Let me know if this helps and for any areas needing extra clarification.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.host.co.uk'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@example.co.uk'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('email@example.co.uk', 'Company Name');
$mail->addAddress($email); //Gets the email the enquiry form field contains
$mail->addReplyTo('email@example.co.uk', 'Company Name');

$body='<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<p>Thank you for your enquiry, a member of the team will be in touch shortly to discuss your requirements. In the mean time, please double check the below details entered on our website. If any of these are incorrect or you wish to add to it, please contact us via email or over the phone.</p></div>';

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject ;
$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

$mail->send();
echo $thankyou_text;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $failed_text;
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your script does basically the same as mine. I took your code and added my own requirements (SMTP server, etc) and while it works when sending an email to my personal Gmail account, the email doesn't seem to be received when sending to WordPress. That's my main issue - WordPress.

Comment: Have you tried using Easy SMTP plugin for wordpress? This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

From a 'Happiness Engineer' at WordPress:

> Hi there!
>
> At WordPress.com we don't allow posts to be sent automatically from
>   scripts such as PHPMailer.

I guess that answers that! Now to forget PHPMailer, and try and get back to default PHP mail() :(

Sorry to have bothered you all

Comment: I don't believe this. It would be interesting to know how they claim to know. It's possible to remove the PHPMailer x-mailer header, so they could not tell it's from PHPMailer. That said, if you're writing a script to send the message into the system, you should be able to call the WordPress API directly from the same place and skip a load of complexity.

Comment: Well, I'm very glad you were skeptical of their "Happiness Engineer", as I looked into removing the PHPMailer x-mailer header, and WOW! It worked first time! A successful post to my blog using PHPMailer, with post body and  email attachment as a post image!